# Java iText: No EOF marker after adding watermark

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to add a watermark to a existing pdf file provided as byte array. I used [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/watermark-examples) example as guideline, but the pdf that I created seems to be missing end-of-file markers and the 'startxref' keyword.

Is there anything that I failed to do right? Or something that is missing?

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPDF);
    PdfStamper stamper;
    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPDF);
    PdfContentByte under = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
    Font f = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15);
    Phrase p = new Phrase(watermarkText, f);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(under, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, 297, 550, 0);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

I checked the pdf file with [this](https://www.pdf-online.com/) tool and these are the errors I get:

```
    Open file.
    0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
        - File: Formular_TEST_Watermark_V1_0.pdf
    0x8041010A - E - The 'startxref' keyword or the xref position was not found.
        - File: Formular_TEST_Watermark_V1_0.pdf
    0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
        - File: Formular_TEST_Watermark_V1_0.pdf
    Close file.
```

EDIT:

The above code is CORRECT, I made a mistake later in the code when transfering the pdf back to the main application, and erroneously made the assumption I must have made a mistake when watermarking because I already transferred pdfs succesfully multiple times, and thought I wouldn't have made a mistake there. My bad.

For completeness, inputPDF and outputPDF are a ByteArrayInputStream and a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: It looks right but you don't show how you save the document and to what. Saving to web is notoriously easy to fail if not done properly, for example. Please post the broken PDF.

Comment: ... and please explain what `inputPDF` and `outputPDF` are.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, your tip set my on the right tracks. The code above is correct and does what it is supposed to do. Returning the xmlencoded watermarked pdf back to the main application is where the error happens, I overlooked a mistake I made there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an hint made by Paulo Soares, I found the true culprit. The code for the watermarking itself in the question is correct and does what it is supposed to do. I updated the question accordingly.